# getopt(): Is optarg guaranteed to be non-NULL if optstring contains something like "a:"?

Tags: c, getopt

When I am writing a piece of code, say something like this:

```
int i_flag;
char *s;
while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "i::o:")) != -1) // I know "i::" is a GNU extension
    switch (c) {
    case 'i':
        i_flag = 1;
        if (optarg != NULL)
            str-i = optarg;
        break;
    case 'o':
        id = strtol (optarg, &s, 0);
        if (id < 0 || id > 5 || *s) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid ID: %s\n", optarg);
            print_usage(); // this function exit()'s the program
        }
        break;
    default:
        print_usage();
    }
```

My question is that I know `optarg` can be NULL in the `'i'` case, but can it be NULL in the `'o'` case? I think it should not be NULL at all, but it does not seem to be guaranteed in POSIX.

I have this question since a very smart static analyzer looks at `if (optarg != NULL)` and says "Oh, so `optarg` can be NULL and you didn't check it in `case 'o'`.

**Update**: Fix `int i-flag;`.

Comment: `int i-flag;` == Error!  Where is `optarg` declared, defined?

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey OK sure `int i_flag = 0;`.
`extern char *optarg;` is declared in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7999959899/functions/getopt.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `optarg` will be non-null.  If a argument is omitted for an option that requires one, `getopt` will return `'?'`.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune That only happens if the very first character in `optstring` is a `':'`

Comment: Can you point to a specification or documentation so I can actually see that it is really so?

Comment: [getopt - Single Unix Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getopt.html)